# How to pass variables from one batch file to another batch file?

Tags: batch-file

How do I write a batch file which gets an input variable and sends it to another batch file to be processed.

**Batch 1**

I don't know how to send a variable to batch 2 which is my problem here.

**Batch 2**

```
if %variable%==1 goto Example
goto :EOF

:Example
echo YaY
```

Comment: You can either pass in the batch1 variables as arguments to batch2, or you can store the variables in a temporary file if you need to run both scripts simultaneously.

Comment: Could you give an example of both please?

Comment: Is batch2 a sub-process of batch1 or an unrelated process?

Comment: batch 2 is a subprocess, batch one is getting a password, batch two recives it and processes it

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't need to do anything at all. Variables set in a batch file are visible in a batch file that it calls.

Example

## test1.bat

```
@echo off
set x=7
call test2.bat
set x=3
call test2.bat
pause
```

## test2.bat

```
echo In test2.bat with x = %x%.
```

## Output

... when test1.bat runs.

```
In test2.bat with x = 7.
In test2.bat with x = 3.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 15):

You can pass in the batch1.bat variables as arguments to batch2.bat.

**arg_batch1.bat**

```
@echo off
cls

set file_var1=world
set file_var2=%computername%
call arg_batch2.bat %file_var1% %file_var2%

:: Note that after batch2.bat runs, the flow returns here, but since there's
:: nothing left to run, the code ends, giving the appearance of ending with
:: batch2.bat being the end of the code.
```

**arg_batch2.bat**

```
@echo off

:: There should really be error checking here to ensure a
:: valid string is passed, but this is just an example.
set arg1=%~1
set arg2=%~2

echo Hello, %arg1%! My name is %arg2%.
```

---

If you need to run the scripts simultaneously, you can use a temporary file.

**file_batch1.bat**

```
@echo off
set var=world

:: Store the variable name and value in the form var=value
:: > will overwrite any existing data in args.txt, use >> to add to the end
echo var1=world>args.txt
echo var2=%COMPUTERNAME%>>args.txt

call file_batch2.bat
```

**file_batch2.bat**

```
@echo off
cls

:: Get the variable value from args.txt
:: Again, there is ideally some error checking here, but this is an example
:: Set no delimiters so that the entire line is processed at once
for /f "delims=" %%A in (args.txt) do (
    set %%A
)

echo Hello, %var1%! My name is %var2%.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading the answers and still getting problems, you may be using `setlocal` wrong.

`setlocal` works like namespaces with `endlocal` closing the last opened namespace.

If you put `endlocal` at the end of your callee as I used to do by default, your variable will be lost in the previously opened `setlocal`.

As long as your variable is set in the same "local" as your caller file's you will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ways. One writes to a file while the other does not.
All include:  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Batch1: (.bat or .cmd)

```
set myvar1=x 1920
set myvar2=y 1080
set myvar > MyConfig.ini
REM    (Use >> to append file and preserve existing entries instead of overwriting.)
```

MyConfig.ini will be created/appended containing:

```
myvar1=x 1920
myvar2=y 1080
```

Batch2:

```
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%I in (myconfig.ini) do set %%I=%%J
```

Then, myvar1 and myvar2 will be set to their stored values.

To avoid any disk file storage, try something I cooked up:

Batch1:

```
(may contain:) start /b cmd /c Batch2.bat
title set myvar1=x 1920^& set myvar2=y 1080
```

Batch2:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('gettitle.exe') do (set titlenow=%%G)
%titlenow%
```

The result is that Batch2 runs the commands...

```
set myvar1=x 1920& set myvar2=y 1080
```

...to replicate the variables from Batch1.
The vars might then be changed and returned to Batch1 in the same manner.
It's ideal for parallel processing AI apps on supercomputers running Windows 10! lol

gettitle.exe is from http://www.robvanderwoude.com

Answer (score -1):

You can find out the solution from below-

```
variable goes here >> "second file goes here.bat"
```

What this code does is that it writes the variables to the second file if existing.Even if it does not exist, it will create a new file.

Comment: could you include how to read the variable in the other file? It isn't being passed unless it is also read in the other batch file