# how do i send information form batchfile1 to batchfile2?

Tags: batch-file, arguments

I created a batchfile to do some testing and I need to send information from batchfile1 to batchfile2

I have to send the ip the user typed in to the second batchfile

my code is

```
    set /p server=Server ip:

    if %server% == ChickIL goto sendinfo

    if not %server% == ChickIL goto sendinfo
```

now how do I receive the %server% variable to my second batchfile. Can I create a note with the info?

I tried nothing because I don't know batch file that good

I think I have to create a note not sure

Comment: It all depends on where these batch files are located regarding each other. As a general solution an intermediate file could be used.

Comment: Possibly using `Call "batchfile2" "%server%"` in `batchfile1`; where `batchfile2` would receive the doublequoted value of the variable as `%1` or the unquoted value of the variable as argument `%~1`.

Comment: they are both in the same folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables from one batch file to another batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595440/how-to-pass-variables-from-one-batch-file-to-another-batch-file).

Comment: yes it might be but i dint understand that one

Comment: no like if i press enter whatever the userver typed in at %server% will be send to notepad file and the other batchfile needs to read the notepad

Comment: skip `notepad`: send to a file and read from the file (like @Ethan suggested).

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done by storing `%server%` into a text file, that will then be read by your second batch file, and stored into another variable. Like this:

```
:sendinfo
echo %server% > server.txt
```

Then in batch file 2, we will have something like this:

```
:start
for /f "Delims=" %%a in (server.txt) do (set server=%%a)
DEL server.txt
```

To break this down for you, `echo %server% > server.txt` stores the variable `%server%` into a text file. Then, over in batch file 2, `for /f "Delims=" %%a in (server.txt) do (set server=%%a)` takes the contents of the server.txt, and then stores it into a variable. And obviously, `DEL server.txt` deletes server.txt, since we no longer need it.

Comment: `echo %server% > server.txt` adds a space. `(echo %server%)>server.txt` or `>server.txt echo %server%` prevents that. As there is just one line in `server.txt`, reading with `<server.txt set /p server=` is good enough.