# How do I pass a variable between two batch files?

Tags: windows, authentication, batch-file, variables, cmd

I want to make a login-feature for one of my batch files using an authorization-tool, and I'm asking myself how I pass the variable of the username from the auth-tool to the initial script.

I've been doing it so far by writing the username into a .txt file and having the main program read it, like this:

```
echo Guest26528 >username.txt
>nul find "Guest26528" username.txt && (set usr=Guest26528)
>nul find "ResAs" username.txt && (set usr=ResAs)
```

But there must be a more efficient way, right?

For anyone interested, this is the authentification-tool:

```
@echo off
color 1F
type authart.txt
echo.
echo.
set /a errorcount = 0
:start
echo Please login to your clearance profile
set /p usr="Username:"
if %usr%==ResAs goto login0
echo Error 303: Unknown Username
goto start 

:login0
set /p pswd="Enter Password for user ResAs:"
if %pswd%==12345 goto pass
echo Error 304: Incorrect password
set /a errorcount = %errorcount% + 1
set /a attempts = 3 - %errorcount%
echo %attempts% Attempts left.
if %errorcount%==3 goto fail
goto login0
    :fail 
    echo Error 305: Too many failed login attempts.
    echo Press any button to continue.
    pause >nul
    exit
    :pass
    echo Login successful.
    echo ResAs >username.txt
```

I'm still very new to this whole coding thing and english isn't my main language, so I hope I wrote my question in an understandable way. I'm excited for your ideas!

Comment: `echo ResAs >username.txt` writes an unwanted space to the file (which later will be read). Avoid this with `(echo ResAs) >username.txt`. It's a single-line file, so you can read it with `set /p usr=<"username.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

I think this can solve your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48264867/14473816

Your solution is good anyway, you can also pass batch1 variables as arguments to batch2.

Answer (score 0):

In place of

```
echo ResAs >username.txt
```

Use

```
initialscript %usr%
```

Within `initialscript`, `%1` will provide the value that was input as `usr`.

Note that as `set /p` accepts any string, the user may input a string containing spaces so

```
if "%usr%"=="ResAs" goto login0
```

is better. In that case, use `initialscript "%usr%"`.

Better, but not foolproof. The user could for instance input `Hel"lo` which would try to execute

```
if "Hel"lo"=="ResAs" goto login0
```

and that would generate a syntax error.

There are many articles on SO which deal with accepting user-input.

Answer (score -1):

The setx command writes a variable into the registry and can be used if you want to use a variable globally for all batch files.

```
SETX VAR_C somevalue
```

Alternatively you could write the variable to a file and read it back into the other batch file ie;

Batch file A:

```
SET VAR_C=somevalue
ECHO %VAR_C% >%TMP%\var_c
```

Batch file B:

```
ECHO %VAR_C%
```

Comment: I wouldn't encourage the use of `setx` for this type of task. Quite apart from the fact that `setx` would not set `var_c` in the current batch, the change is permanent until erased so repeated use of the method over many batch files would load the environment with untold amounts of one-use data. Your second suggestion unfortunately is precisely what OP is currently using, and `Batch B` simply will not work as expected since the file is not being read.